# How to return page views for each day of the past week?

Tags: php, symfony, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

> ga:pageviews

## How to return page views for each day of the past week?

I can only get the total page views for a certain period of time

The following figure is the analysis result I expected

[image]

[image]

## my code

```
$pageViews = $analyticsService->getPageViewsDateRange($viewId,'30daysAgo','today')
```

Comment: What have you tried please include your code.

Comment: @da
DaThank you very much for your reply and help

I use GitHub: [Google Analytics API Symfony Bundle](https://github.com/mediafigaro/google-analytics-api-symfony)
[Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/?#ga:pageviews)
`
// Get page views for the past week
$pageViews = $analyticsService->getPageViewsDateRange($viewId,'7daysAgo','today');
`

Comment: That code is not complete.   what dimensions and metrics are you sending what dates,   what is the request returning?  what should it be returning unfortunately your pictures are not in English.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have successfully obtained the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Thank you DaImTo The following code can get the analysis results I want, I hope it can help others

I use[Google Analytics API Symfony Bundle](https://github.com/mediafigaro/google-analytics-api-symfony)

```
        //Get daily views for the past week
        $pageView = $analyticsService->getDataDateRangeMetricsDimensions($viewId, '7daysAgo', 'today', ['pageviews'], ['date']);

        //Get page views every hour of the day
        $pageView = $analyticsService->getDataDateRangeMetricsDimensions($viewId, 'today', 'today', ['pageviews'], ['hour']);
```